# Scroll to div after page load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to make my page scroll to div `id='#pageload'`
if it is loaded from url `http://www.website.com/#pageload`

I used the code below but all pages redirect to `http://www.website.com/#pageload`

```
if(document.location ="/#pageload") {
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#pageload').offset().top
    }, 'slow');
}
```

How can I fix it? Thank you very much.

Comment: shouldn't it be  `if(document.location.hash ="#pageload")` ?

Comment: Hi. It is not work.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of syntax errors seem to be in your code. Note that in your if() you used one equal sign *(assignment sign)*, when you should use two or three *(assertion sign)*. Check out the snippet sample.

```js
//you can get rid off that part
document.location.hash="#d";  //set url /#d dynamically
document.body.scrollTop = "0px";  //set scroll to 0
//you can get rid off that part

if(document.location.hash === "#d"){
 
        $('body').animate({
                scrollTop: $('#d').offset().top
        }, 'slow');
      }
```

```css
.cont{
  width: 200px;
  height:500px;
  margin:10px;
  background-color:#fce4ec;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="cont" id="a">a</div>
<div class="cont" id="b">b</div>
<div class="cont" id="c">c</div>
<div class="cont" id="d">d</div>
<div class="cont" id="e">e</div>
<div class="cont" id="f">f</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to make my page scroll to `div id='#pageload'` if it is loaded
>   from url `http://www.website.com/#pageload`

The key consideration here is that you need to use a hash fragment which is *different* from the `id` of the element you wish the newly loaded window to scroll down to.

If the hash fragment and the element `id` are identical, the window, as it loads, will automatically position itself with that element at the top of the viewport... and then there will be nowhere for the window to scroll to and, consequently, no animation.

In the example below,

- the hash fragment is `#topageload`
- the element `id` is `#pageload`

**Working Example:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

    // The line below (and the second condition involving winLocHash are included just so this example works
    var winLocHash = '#toppageload';

    if ((window.location.hash === '#topageload') || (winLocHash === '#toppageload')) {
        $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $("#pageload").offset().top}, 3000);
    }

});
```

```css
body {
    background-color: rgb(255,255,0);
}

div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin: 24px;
}

div:nth-of-type(odd) {
    background-color: rgb(255,0,0);
}

div:nth-of-type(even) {
    background-color: rgb(0,0,255);
}

#pageload {
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    line-height: 100px;
    font-weight: bold; 
    text-align: center;
    background-color: rgb(0,127,0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>

<div id="pageload">#Pageload</div>

<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
```